# PHP NumberFormatter always gives me the default en_US

Tags: php, docker, alpine-linux, intl

When trying to format currency in my PHP 8.1 alpine docker container I always get the default locale (en_US).

```
$ docker run -it --rm php:8.1-fpm-alpine /bin/ash
# apk update && apk add icu-dev
# docker-php-ext-configure intl && docker-php-ext-install intl
# php -a
> $formatter = new NumberFormatter('nl_NL', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
> echo $formatter->getLocale();
en_US
> echo $formatter->format(1234.567);
€1,234.57
```

I expect getLocale() to return nl_NL and format to return €1.234,57.

If I try locale en_GB, getLocale() does return en_GB.

Any tips on writing a better question are welcome too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the [`icu-dev`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/icu-dev) package, also install the [`icu-data-full`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/icu-data-full) package. By default, only [`icu-data-en`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/icu-data-en) is installed, which contains American and British English as you've seen, but no Dutch.

The split was introduced in [Alpine 3.16.0](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Release_Notes_for_Alpine_3.16.0#ICU_data_split), probably as a space-saving measure: the full package weighs about 29 MB installed, which is big compared to the rest of the image.

With the full data installed, your example gives

```
php > echo $formatter->getLocale();
nl_NL
php > echo $formatter->format(1234.567);
€ 1.234,57
```

as expected.